# Connection Pooling in a java chat server

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have already developed a LAN client-server chat application in java.My server establishes connection  to a mysql database using jdbc where i save client information.Now i want to know should i use Connection pooling in server for establishing connection to mysql.Can anyone tell me if i am on the right track.I actually came across this concept on internet and i thought of implementing it in my project.Can anyone just tell me if it is necessary to use connection pooling and if it can be helpful for my chat application.

Comment: how many clients will be connecting at the same time ?

Comment: @Peter-  Max 100 clients

Comment: what are the tasks database will do? is it just login? or you will be logging all messages exchanged between all clients?

Comment: @Yazan-Not only login but messages will also be saved.Also login for conference users and messages exchanged will be saved.

Comment: @user3849377 , maybe a pooling will be good then, or implementing a simple Q that any inserting operations is added to, then a 1 or 2 threads will work on that Q, so you have 1 or 2 connections to the db. and all clients (using chat-server) will insert into that Q

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Peter said - it is a good practice to use a connection pool when your server connected to the db server. So the answer is - "Yes it is ok and it will work but you'd better use a connection pool there".

Comment: Please unheck my post as an answer. @Peter did actually answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

When 100 clients will be connecting at the same time its always a good idea to use a Connection pool, its not necessary its just a good practice, there are plenty of article on the internet on why.

but ONLY if the connections are made from a central server. If each client will be creating its own connection and then closing it then its useless to make a connection pool in your client, it only needs  1 anyway.

Comment: @Peter-Only server will be establishing  a connection with mysql.So is it ok if i dont use connection pooling.